# Best practise to cache data in microservice architecture with multiple instances

Tags: caching, microservices

There is a challenge we face in some of our java-spring miscroservice application and not sure if are using the efficient possible way to solve it.

Usually in distributed systems, we have microservices and each service has more than 1 instance, sometimes 2 or 3 or 6 depending on load service is supposed to serve.

We come across cases where we have a possibility to cache data to avoid DB calls which is the single instance for tomcat instances running and improve performance.

Given we implement a cache - Guava/Caffeine and say a record with key-"A" is cached in instance_1/instance_2. There has been an update for "A" on instance_1. we always have to let instance_2 know that there has been an update for "A" and invalidate "A" from the cache of instance_2.
We typically use messaging here to send this on a topic and instance_1/instance_2 will both listen and invalidate/evict "A" from cache. This messaging is a bit heavy for a small cache implementation we do. Is there a more efficient way to do this in Restful microsevices.

Any advice would be of great help.

Comment: I think it would be better if you could use a central cache like redis.

Comment: I would also recommend using a distributed cache.